# what would be an appropriate way to migrate mongo db data to SQL SERVER?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a nodejs application for API end points and I want to change it to ASP.NET Core Web Api. The problem is the data that is in the Mongo db, what would be an appropriate way to migrate monago db data to SQL SERVER? like exporting mongo db data as json file or CSV etc then uploading that to SQL SERVER. Thank you.

Comment: You're developer, write a migration tool

Comment: Why can't you use mongo wirh core? You're asking how to migrate a non sql document db to relational sql db.

Comment: Use mongodb c# driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to moving the entire Mongo DB to the SQL-Server platform your best approach is to use SQL-Server SSIS with the Mongo C# driver.  Here is a link on how to do that:

https://arcanecode.com/2014/01/14/importing-mongodb-data-using-ssis-2012/

If you would rather just manipulate the MongoDB from your C# project look at his link:

https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/

The only issue is that I do not know if this library will work with Net.Core.  But you can research that yourself

:)...